# Mixed Network Configuration - Lixux / Mac / Windows - Name Resolution

Tags: networking, router

I have a home network where some of the machines have static IP addresses, and the rest have their IP addresses allocated by a DHCP server which runs on my broad band router. The broad band router also provides wired and wireless access and acts as the gateway to the internet.

The machines with static IP addresses only have static IP's because they provide services ( such as printers ) that I want the other machines to be able to access.

What I'd really like to do is to be able to access the machines in my network by name rather than IP address, but I don't know where to start. I don't even know what to Google ...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: NetBIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to go about this is to assign each device a hostname. That should allow you to refer to a given device on your network through its defined hostname.

As far as Linux systems, I believe you can simply use the command 'hostname'. But there are other ways of going about that for Debian-based and RedHat-based systems respectively.

Comment: That doesn't see to work for me : ~$ hostname
dave-Aspire-X1420
~$ ping dave-Aspire-X1420
ping: unknown host dave-Aspire-X1420